# Iphone4 and GPS alternatives

Tags: ios4, accelerometer, compass-geolocation, gyroscope

provided GPS will not work precisely in closed environment like rooms etc,I m interested to know whether Accelerometer can be used to find the position of object relative to certain point? If not then what other technology iphone4 provides to cater it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The accelerometer cannot reliably provide location information, even with the aid of the gyroscope. GPS is the best you are likely to get.

OTOH, work-arounds abound in the augmented-reality space. Consider the [ARDefender](http://www.ardefender.com/) game.

Comment: But GPS does not work quite accurate in closed environment like Rooms etc. Imagine I want to take photo of a container in my room. GPS will not tell the exact location. Accelerometer would sure not locate exact position but will accelerometer record X,Y and Z coordinate on movement? and Gyroscope to note angle

Comment: @Volatil3: I didn't say GPS was a *good* solution for indoor use. We would all love to have micrometer and microsecond spatial-temporal resolution everywhere from the bathroom to the nearest star, but the technology just isn't there yet. That's life.

Comment: right. Coming to my main question. Say if I activate Accelerometer and at certain point I call it (0,0,0). If I move my mobile at certain direction, will accelerometer record the position of XYZ? And if I m storing that points in Db, I am moving again in same direction or reach to near by or same point that was previously recorded by Acclerometer, will I be able to "sense" it(promatically)?

Comment: I've experimented with this; it doesn't work. Even with the aid of the gyroscope, the accelerometer drifts very quickly and the computed position becomes meaningless within seconds. In fact, it becomes meaningless after the first jerky movement due to the limited rate at which the system reads the accelerometer.

Comment: so how apps like "Free Pedometer" for iPhone calculating things? Is it because they are using accelerometer+Steps counting algo?

Comment: Since it's designed for outdoor use, it probably uses a combination of GPS and step-counting. Perhaps it even uses the GPS to calibrate meters-per-step.